# central align an input using bootstrap css

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using `Bootstrap 3 CSS`. Below is my markup for an input:

```
<div class="module module_buy_and_sell_filters">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p>Filter buy and sells</p>
      <input style="" class="span6 form-control" value="4" id="sl1" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is display of my code:

[image]

Can you please guide me how I can center align input (slider blue lined)  with parent div (black lined) using bootstrap.

Please note I dont want to write custom CSS, I want to use bootstrap classes for it.

Thanks for your help and guidance.

Comment: can you show us the code via bootply.com or jsfiddle ?

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right way, but I usually evenly distribute spans inside the well (or whatever it is your're working inside of:) ). So If my well is span6, I create three div's inside of span2 and place my content in the appropriate one. I also make sure they're fluid.

Answer (score 0):

Remove any pull-left, pull-right classes that you might have applied to the slider div, and apply following styles:

for slider div

```
display: inline-block;
margin: 0px auto;
```

for slider container

```
text-align: center;
```